# Problema alternando fgets e scanf_s

Tags: c, string, struct

Eu tenho um problema que o usuário tem que inserir o nome e idade de 5 pessoas, e tem que imprimir na tela o nome da pessoa mais nova.

Eu fiz o seguinte código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pessoa {
    char nome[1000];
    int idade;

};

int main() {
    pessoa pessoa1;
    pessoa pessoa2;
    pessoa pessoa3;
    pessoa pessoa4;
    pessoa pessoa5;

    printf("\n Insira o nome da primeira pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa1.nome, 1000, stdin);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da segunda pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa2.nome, 1000, stdin);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da terceira pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa3.nome, 1000, stdin);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da quarta pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa4.nome, 1000, stdin);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da quinta e ultima pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa5.nome, 1000, stdin);

    printf("\n Insira a idade da primeira pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa1.idade);

    printf("\n Insiraa idade da segunda pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa2.idade);

    printf("\n Insira a idade da terceira pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa3.idade);

    printf("\n Insira a idade da quarta pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa4.idade);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da quinta e ultima pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa5.idade);

    pessoa pessoaMaisNova;
    pessoaMaisNova.idade = 150;


    if (pessoa1.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
        pessoaMaisNova = pessoa1;
    }

    if (pessoa2.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
        pessoaMaisNova = pessoa2;
    }

    if (pessoa3.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
        pessoaMaisNova = pessoa3;
    }

    if (pessoa4.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
        pessoaMaisNova = pessoa4;
    }

    if (pessoa5.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
        pessoaMaisNova = pessoa5;
    }

    printf("\n Nome da pessoa mais nova: %s", pessoaMaisNova.nome);
}
```

Assim fica tudo ok, mas quando eu faço a seguinte mudança, alternando fgets e scanf_s (em vez de fazer todos fgets primeiro e depois os scanf_s):

```
    printf("\n Insira o nome da primeira pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa1.nome, 1000, stdin);
    printf("\n Insira a idade da primeira pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa1.idade);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da segunda pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa2.nome, 1000, stdin);
    printf("\n Insiraa idade da segunda pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa2.idade);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da terceira pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa3.nome, 1000, stdin);
    printf("\n Insira a idade da terceira pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa3.idade);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da quarta pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa4.nome, 1000, stdin);
    printf("\n Insira a idade da quarta pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa4.idade);

    printf("\n Insira o nome da quinta e ultima pessoa: ");
    fgets(pessoa5.nome, 1000, stdin);
    printf("\n Insira o nome da quinta e ultima pessoa: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pessoa5.idade);
```

Quando rodo o código, eu consigo digitar o nome da primeira pessoa, a idade da primeira pessoa, mas ele pula para a idade da segunda pessoa (não consigo digitar o nome). O mesmo acontece com as outras pessoas. Por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 0):

#### Eu fiz algumas modificações

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pessoa {
  char nome[1000];
  int idade;
};

int main() {
  struct pessoa pessoa1;
  struct pessoa pessoa2;
  struct pessoa pessoa3;
  struct pessoa pessoa4;
  struct pessoa pessoa5;

  printf("\n Insira o nome da primeira pessoa: ");
  fgets(pessoa1.nome, 1000, stdin);

  printf("\n Insira o nome da segunda pessoa: ");
  fgets(pessoa2.nome, 1000, stdin);

  printf("\n Insira o nome da terceira pessoa: ");
  fgets(pessoa3.nome, 1000, stdin);

  printf("\n Insira o nome da quarta pessoa: ");
  fgets(pessoa4.nome, 1000, stdin);

  printf("\n Insira o nome da quinta e ultima pessoa: ");
  fgets(pessoa5.nome, 1000, stdin);

  printf("\n Insira a idade da primeira pessoa: ");
  scanf("%d", &pessoa1.idade);

  printf("\n Insiraa idade da segunda pessoa: ");
  scanf("%d", &pessoa2.idade);

  printf("\n Insira a idade da terceira pessoa: ");
  scanf("%d", &pessoa3.idade);

  printf("\n Insira a idade da quarta pessoa: ");
  scanf("%d", &pessoa4.idade);

  printf("\n Insira o nome da quinta e ultima pessoa: ");
  scanf("%d", &pessoa5.idade);

  struct pessoa pessoaMaisNova;
  pessoaMaisNova.idade = 150;

  if (pessoa1.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
    pessoaMaisNova = pessoa1;
  }

  if (pessoa2.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
    pessoaMaisNova = pessoa2;
  }

  if (pessoa3.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
    pessoaMaisNova = pessoa3;
  }

  if (pessoa4.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
    pessoaMaisNova = pessoa4;
  }

  if (pessoa5.idade < pessoaMaisNova.idade) {
    pessoaMaisNova = pessoa5;
  }

  printf("\n Nome da pessoa mais nova: %s", pessoaMaisNova.nome);
}
```

#### Inseri os seguintes dados:

```
Ella-Mai Jensen
Michael Roche
Tazmin Powell
Ahmet Corrigan
Layton Barlow
51
32
86
85
46
```

#### E foi produzido o seguinte resultado:

```
Nome da pessoa mais nova: Michael Roche
```